# Facebook Secure Login with App Engine Proxy

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, authentication

Trying to make an app engine proxy server that lets me access facebook from sites that block it.

I follow the tutorial at http://lifehacker.com/5484934/run-your-own-free-proxy-through-the-google-app-engine
but it seems like secure logins are not supported.
I know there are proxy websites that let me access, but i don't like the idea of my password floating past a middleman.
Any idea on how to implement an app engine proxy with secure login support?